# How to add Realm to Android target of Kotlin multiplatform library project?

Tags: gradle, realm, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to add Realm to the android target of my Kotlin multiplatform library but I get this error:

```
Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'library (:library)'.
Read more https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#setting-up-targets
```

I can add Realm to any Android project without issues, but when I try to add it to a multiplatform library it doesn't work. Here's my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("realm-android")
}

kotlin {
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64
    android()
    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
                implementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.6")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
    }
}
val artifactName = "library"
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        base.archivesBaseName = "${artifactName}-${versionName}"
    }
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
}
```

If I remove the line `id("realm-android")` it builds fine, but there's no Realm.

Comment: You can add that Plugin in `android` `build.gradle` instead of shared `build.gradle` and it should work fine i guess

Comment: Also you can go through this link for adding realm in KMM :- https://github.com/realm/realm-kotlin/blob/master/examples/kmm-sample/shared/build.gradle.kts

Comment: @MohammedHanif. That repository is for the experimental kotlin multiplatform realm library. How can I add a build.gradle to be used only when compiling for android?

Comment: `How can I add a build.gradle to be used only when compiling for android?` What do you mean by this ? You already have a `build.gradle` for android seperately you can add such dependencies which are required by android only such as - `Constraint Layout` in android `buiild.gradle` itself